# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. how to fix? (

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I was installing plib-1.8.0, i extracted .tar.gz, then opened terminal in the new extracted folder, the ran this command:

```
./configure
```

And got this output:

```
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
includedir changed to ${prefix}/include/plib libdir is ${exec_prefix}/lib
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for executable suffix...
checking for object suffix... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux
checking for X... libraries , headers
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
checking for glNewList in -lGL... no
checking for glNewList in -lMesaGL... no
configure: error: could not find working GL library
```

how can i fix it, and install plib-1.8.0 successfully

Comment: i have installed it

Comment: Make sure you have the "-dev" packages for OpenGL installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `config.log` file, you will likely see that the `glNewList` conftest is not necessarily reporting the real reason for its failure. In my case for example:

```
configure:6841: checking for glNewList in -lGL
configure:6876: gcc -o conftest -g -O2    conftest.c -lGL    -lXi -lXmu -lXext -lX11  -lm >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:6882: $? = 1
```

So you need to also make sure that your system has the various X11 development libraries - I only needed to install `libxmu-dev` as the others were already present but you may need `libxi-dev` as well (the others should be installed as dependencies).

If disk space is not an issue, the `xorg-dev` metapackage should install everything you need and more.